# DIV height to fill the rest of the page, with twist

Tags: javascript, css, xhtml, html

How do I make a div expand with it's own content to fill the existing space ?
The Structure is this ( I am using 960Grid ). 
I need the DIV1, DIV2, DIV3 and DIV4 to fill the (viewport) Height available, if there is not much content.
Or if there is, that the DIV1, DIV2, DIV3 expand their height with the DIV4 content.

```
+--------------------------------+
|      +------------------+      |
|      | Logo    Buttons  |      |
|      |                  |      |
|      +------------------+      |
|================================|
|      +------------------+      |
|      |Title             |      |
|      |                  |      |
|      +------------------+      |
|==============DIV1==============|---  
|      +-------DIV2-------+      |  ^
|      |+DIV3+ +---DIV4--+|      |  |
|      ||    | |         ||      |  |
|      ||Menu| | Content ||      |  |   
|      ||    | |         ||      |  div
|      ||    | |         ||      |  100% of page (not screen) height
|      ||    | |         ||      |  |
|      ||    | |         ||      |  |
|      |+----+ +---------+|      |  |
|      +------------------+      |  v 
|================================|---
|      +------------------+      |
|      |Footer            |      |
|      +------------------+      |
+--------------------------------+
```

When I dont scroll everything is OK
[image: When I dont scroll everything is OK]

When I scroll the body (in Green) appears
[image: When I scroll the body (in Green) appears]

HTML CODE:

```
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <div class="container_16">
            <div id="logo" class="grid_5" onclick="window.location='home.php'">

            </div>
            <div class="grid_3">
                &nbsp;
            </div>

            <div class="botao grid_2 fs5">
                <a href="sobre.php">About</a>
            </div>

            <div class="botao grid_2 fs5">
                <a href="profissao.php">Services</a>
            </div>

            <div class="botao grid_2 fs5">
                <a href="noticias.php">Products</a>
            </div>

            <div class="botao grid_2 fs5">
                <a href="eventos.php">Contact</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- end #header -->

    <div id="page_name">
        <div class="container_16">
            <div id="name" class="grid_16">
                <h1>Title</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- end #page_name -->

    <div id="top_shadow"></div>

    <div id="page_wrapper">
        <div class="container_16">
            <div id="menu" class="grid_4">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">Start</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">We</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">You</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Web</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">ROI</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- end #menu -->
            <div id="page_content" class="grid_12">
                <div class="text">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed eu lorem tellus, et posuere lectus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Curabitur orci sem, ultrices non consectetur sed, ullamcorper eu magna. Praesent sit amet sollicitudin odio. Donec et urna vel diam pellentesque elementum ut eget lorem. Ut in augue enim, eu varius elit. Aenean quam risus, suscipit in dapibus ut, consequat quis magna. Quisque vulputate vestibulum tempus. Nam tristique tempus mi, a fringilla metus tempor eget. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla velit nibh, pulvinar id rutrum sed, iaculis non turpis....
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div><!-- end .text -->
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div><!-- end #page_content -->
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div><!-- end .container_16 -->
        <div class="clear"></div>

    </div><!-- end #page_wrapper -->


    <div id="footer">
        <div class="container_16">
            <div id="news1" class="grid_10">
                <p class="white creditos fs6">© Footer</p>
            </div>

            <div id="apoio" class="grid_6 direita">
                <p class="white creditos fs6">Text</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- end #footer -->              
</body>
```

CSS Code:

```
html, body {height: 100%;}

body {
    padding: 0px;
}

.clear { clear: both; }

#header{
    background: url(../images/header_bg.png) repeat-x;
    height: 60px;
    position:relative;
}

#logo{
    margin-top: 10px;
    background:  url(../images/Logo.png) no-repeat;
    height: 40px;
    cursor:pointer;
}

#destaque{
    background:  url(../images/destaque_bg.png) repeat-x;
    height: 330px;
}

#top_shadow{
    background: transparent url(../images/anuncios_bg.png) repeat-x;
    background-position: top;
    height:6px;
    width:100%;
    z-index:800;
    position:relative;
}

#page_name{
    background:  url(../images/destaque_bg.png) repeat-x;
    height: 80px;
    position:relative;
}

#page_name #name{
    margin-top:30px;
}

/*body > #page_wrapper {height:auto;}*/

#page_wrapper{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    margin-top:-6px;
    position:absolute;
    top:145px;
    bottom:45px;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}


#page_wrapper div.container_16{ 
    background-color: green;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -480px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    overflow:visible;
}



#menu{
    background: #fff url(../images/menu_bg.png) right top repeat-y;
    margin: auto;
    height:100%;
    overflow: visible; 
    z-index:10;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
}

#menu ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

#menu ul li{
    background: transparent url(../images/categoria_separador.png) 5px bottom no-repeat;
    width: 227px;
    height: 40px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    overflow:visible;
}

#menu ul li:hover{
}

#menu  ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    display:block;
    font-size:15px;
    color: #000000;

    width: 219px;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 11px 0 0 20px;
    margin-top:-2px;
}

#menu  ul li:hover a{
    background: transparent url(../images/categoria_bg.png) left top scroll;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    overflow:visible;
}


#page_content{
    display:block;
    background-color: blue;

}

#page_content div.text{
    padding:25px 0 0 25px;
}

#anuncios{
    background: #fff url(../images/anuncios_bg.png) repeat-x;
    background-position: top;
    height: 360px;

}

#footer{
    background-color: #000000;
    margin-top: -45px;
    height: 45px;
    clear:both;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    bottom:0px;
    z-index:999;
}

#shelf{
    background:  url(../images/shelf.png) no-repeat center 147px white;
    height: 192px;
    overflow:visible;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}


#shelf div.book{
    height: 110px;
    /*background-color:yellow;*/
    margin-top: 0px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
}

#shelf div.book a  {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
}

/*
#shelf div.book a img:hover{
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px -1px 2px #555;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px -1px 3px #999;
    box-shadow: 1px -1px 2px #555;
    margin-bottom:-2px;
}*/

#shelf h2{
    height: 35px;
}

#nba{
    background:  url(../images/news_b_apoios.png) no-repeat;
    background-position: right;
    height: 100px;
}

#eventos, #concursos{
    background:  url(../images/separador.png) no-repeat;
    background-position: right;
}

#eventos, #concursos, #noticias{
    margin-top: 26px;
    height: 298px;
}

#concursos h2{
    margin-left:40px;
}

#concursos div{
    margin-left:30px;
}

#noticias h2{
    margin-left:30px;
}

#noticias div{
    margin-left:20px;
}

.anuncio{
    margin-top: 9px;
    margin-left:-10px;
    height: 120px;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.anuncio:hover{
    background:  url(../images/anuncio_bg.png) no-repeat;
}

#noticia_destaque{
    margin-top:63px;
}

.texto_noticia_destaque{
    line-height: 20px;
    text-align: justify;
    width: 370px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

#painel{
    background:  url(../images/Painel-de-fotos.png) repeat-x;
    height: 284px;
    margin-top:28px;

}


.botao{
        height: 30px;
        color:#fff;
        margin-top:10px;
        cursor:pointer;
}


.botao:hover{
    background:  url(../images/botao_bg.png) no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}

.botao a{
        color:#fff;
        text-decoration: none;
}


.creditos{
    margin-top:17px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to give `body` a `height: 100%` and DIV1 a `min-height: 100%`.